# TikZ in boxes – repeated evaluation?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Because of positioning and other issues, I have come up with code doing things like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    Word
    \raisebox{\depth}{\(
        \tikzset{every picture/.append style={baseline={(0,1)}}}
        \tikz\draw (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
        \to
        \tikz\draw (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
    \)}
    word
\end{document}
```

So, a `tikzpicture` inside a `\raisebox`. Other things I frequently use are tikzpictures in `\(math)makebox`, `\underset`, `\under-` and `\overbrace` and others. I somehow came to the belief that some of these evaluate the picture multiple times, probably to get its size. But the problem is that this takes quite a while, given that the pictures are more complicated, and there are many of them, occuring probably in beamer slides with many overlays.

My question is: what commands should I avoid placing tikzpictures in with regard repeated evaluation, and what are other possible remedies?

Comment: the box is only evaluated once.

Comment: beamer  overlays are re-evaluations so to avoid that you could box first outside the frame and use the box in the overlay

Comment: Depending on the context math-mode content might be evaluated four times so that LaTeX has access to the different versions depending on the math style. Possible remedy is to use the `external` library (or other tools that achieve the same). You still might get four evaluations but only on the first run, later only the PDFs get included.

Comment: The `amsmath` environments like `align` also evaluate content twice, once for measuring once to actually typeset.